# How to make the div stay on the top of the view point on the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my div stay on the top of the view point no matter how far down you scroll.  This is my code so far:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
#mydiv {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:30em;
    height:18em;
    margin-top: -9em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    margin-left: -15em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
</style>
<div id="mydiv">Test Div</div>
```

I have looked up many things about this but none work. Help!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
position: fixed;
```

**Tip**: when curious about how is xxx implemented in css, you can always examine the source code of websites that have already been using it.

Comment: Sorry i am only 11 and kind of new to programming

Comment: Note the navbar in [link](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/). That navbar has property 'position' set to 'fixed'. You delete that property and it's no longer fixed. Maybe you can try it without setting the top or left property?

Comment: This is the same as above!

Answer (score 1):

Change the `position` property to `fixed`:

```
position: fixed;
```

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position):

> **position: fixed**
>    Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and doesn't move when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on every page.

Comment: @EthanBacon:  There must be more to your page then you are including in the question.  You should provide the full code that's not working in your question.

Comment: I have given the full code on this page.  I'm not sure whats happening.

Comment: @EthanBacon Not sure what to tell you, because `position: fixed` works for me:  http://tinker.io/e11aa.  Are you using an older iphone?

Comment: i phone?  I'm using a laptop with IE9

Answer (score 0):

add the following code in your program clear : both; top : 0px;